# How can I make a css class change on hover?

Tags: html, css

So here I have two different things defined:

```
<running>Running.</running>

<showr>Cross-Country, Track</showr>
```

The user should hover on "running" and that will make "showr" be displayed.

Here is the css that I have; I can't make it work.

```
showr { display:none; }

showr running:hover { display:inline; }
```

Can you please explain how I can make this work? (some CSS would be good)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain what type of elements running and showr are, so I used divs and wrote this code which does work.  Assuming that running and showr are block elements, it should work just to replace the div tags with those.

```
<div id='running' onMouseOver="document.getElementById('showr').style.display='inline'" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('showr').style.display='none'">Running.</div>

<div id='showr' style='display:none'>Cross-Country, Track</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make `<showr>` a child of `<running>`:

```
<running>Running.<showr>Cross-Country, Track</showr></running>
```

CSS:

```
showr { display:none; }

running:hover showr { display:inline; }
```

However, this doesn't work on IE because IE did not implement CSS properly.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FZCCg/ (I replaced the tag names with classes for valid html)

Comment: This isn't an advanced selector at all! However, `:hover` only works in links in IE6.

Comment: @pst: Thanks, I knew it didnt work for IE, and most advanced selectors dont work for IE... 1+1

Comment: I actually need them to be separate, as the second one is on a different part of the page. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Perhaps in a few years we can use IE8 as the base-line ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
showr running { display: none}

showr:hover running { display: inline }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work. Thanks for trying to help, though. I think the issue with this code is that the two tags are not one within the other, so doing it like this wouldn't work.

Comment: @Andrew: Well of course. In order to be able to do this without nesting them, you'd have to use JavaScript.

Comment: @musicfreak Not necessarily true. There are sibling selectors, e.g., which could be used.

Comment: @pst: Well, not without support from the major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It requires that your CSS uses an adjacent sibling selector (or similar) such as `running:hover + showr { display:inline; }` -- or, as others have suggested, create a parent-sibling relationship by changing the markup.

This is because the actual style *is only ever applied to the SUBJECT of the selector that matches*. This is also why the adjacent sibling form can work and why *nesting is not required*, from [5.7 Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors):

> > Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

I am not sure which browsers, if any (not IE6 for sure!), will support adjacent siblings correctly though. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html for the CSS selector rules and [quirksmode - CSS](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) for the general compatibility. Also, the `:hover` pseudo-class is entirely broken on IE6 -- surprise!

On the other hand, this is trivial to do with jQuery and the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event, trading a working CSS2 requirement for a JavaScript requirement ;-)